# Unable to use range slider wth text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jquery and i want whenever we increase/decrease "slider range" then "text" should increase/decrease according to selection,How can we do this ? I tried with following code
but not working for me,Thank you in advance.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('input').on('input', e => $('p').css('font-size', $(e.target).val() + 'em'));
</script>
<input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
<p>Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>
```

Comment: Your code work, only problem is that your script gets executed before your input is rendered. Move your script to the end of your code and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your script under input like this one

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" value="1.2" min="1.2" max="2.6" step=".0002" id="slider" />
<p>Some text that should dynamically change size.</p>

<script>
$('input').on('input', e => $('p').css('font-size', $(e.target).val() + 'em'));
</script>
```

Comment: Changing from arrow function to "normal" function, does not solve the problem.

Comment: @bobi still not working

Comment: @Jim i update answer as Carsten suggest just move it under the input or at the end of the file